# Conditional Formatting based on relative column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet in which I created a conditional formatting rule:

> if columnB > 50 then columnA fill color green.

The result is OK for the whole of columnA, based on columnB. The problem is that when I copy the format to columnX this should be based on columnY but remains based on columnB.

I need an automatic way to format the cells based on the neighbouring column and not a fixed column.

Comment: see the tag excerpt for `conditional-formatting` and `excel` (*hover over the tags in your question*)

Comment: @pnuts that question is clearly a SuperUser question. It has completely nothing to do with *programming*.

Comment: I have my right to vote and I'm choosing that this question (and many others like this one) is/are off-topic on SO. By leaving it here we give an example for future users that those type of questions are on-topic on Stack Overflow while I truly believe they are better suitable on SU. There isn't an official reference but the tag excerpt + info. Going by those principles I think this question should be migrated. Also `I NEED` are discouraged specially when they show no attempts at trying and no research. Feel free to post a discussion on meta regarding this specific question.

Comment: @pnuts I don't like what you're implying to a no.6 top user in VBA tag, with 10 gold badges, 32 silver, and 56 brown which includes nearly all participation and moderation related badges. Someone who   roughly spends 8hr/day on Stack Overflow as well as on MSO.

Comment: @pnuts my close vote means this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. I am not trying to migrate it - simply just close it. Those better fit SU.

Comment: My Vote also to delete it completly or close it, it blocks me to ask questions.

Answer (score 4):

Take the anchor (`$`) off the front of your `B` in the formula for the formatting being copied before copying.

Comment: thanks for reply. i removed the sign from column and row, but excel converts B2 to a strange number.

Answer (score 1):

In conditional formatting is it listed the following:

$2$B>50

If this is the case then take away the $.  Should look at this:

2B>50

BY doing this when you copy and paste it not stay on column B

Comment: thanks for reply. it still not working , when i write 2B>50, excel converts it to a strange number.NOT B2