# Conditional Formatting Based on Prior Columns Data

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I read another post ([Conditional Formatting based on relative column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547723/conditional-formatting-based-on-relative-column)) but the answer did not work for me and I am unable to comment due to low reputation.

I have a reporting spreadsheet where column J represents data as of last update and column K represents data from current update. [image: Spreadsheet Example] and I am trying to see the changes in any data points using conditional formatting.

The problem arises when Excel starts to compare a date to a number (as seen in column L compared to column K). I want to be able to dictate to Excel that it should not evaluate one after the other (K-J;L-K) but that it should move in groupings (K-J;M-L;O-N) essentially skipping over the prior used column in the evaluation.

Any and all ideas appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=OR(AND(J2<>K2,ISEVEN(COLUMN(J2))),AND(I2<>J2,ISODD(COLUMN(J2))))
```

or

```
=OR(AND(J2<>K2,ISODD(COLUMNS($J:J))),AND(I2<>J2,ISEVEN(COLUMNS($J:J))))
```

is better because not affected by columns being inserted/deleted before column J.

[image]

Comment: Tom, great idea, but when I copy the formula into my conditional formatting, and then apply the rule to a selection of $K$2:$O$113 it evaluates each column against the one preceding it [Screenshot of spreadsheet](http://screencast.com/t/gyv6aDsB)

Comment: My formula only works properly if you apply it starting with column J i.e. $J$2:$O$113 in your case and it highlights both cells which have a mismatch. if you wanted to start from column K and just highlight the right-hand cell of each pair, you'd need =AND(J2<>K2,ISODD(COLUMNS($K:K)))

Comment: I don't know why at this point, but I am still not getting the results you posted. [Screenshot of spreadsheet](http://screencast.com/t/d9YaMW0I2). Instead I ALWAYS have the right hand of the pair (ISEVEN, not ISODD) highlighted even when data does equal its pairing. I only expanded out the selections from $J$2:$ZZ$113. See on screengrab where the red arrows point, desired result pointed out in green arrow.

Comment: If you're starting formatting from column J and want to highlight the right-hand cell of each pair, you'd need =AND(I2<>J2,ISEVEN(COLUMNS(K:$K))) . So in cell J2, even if I2<>J2, the rule isn't applied because COLUMNS(K:$K) =1 so is odd. When you move across to cell K2, the formula changes to =AND(J2<>K2,ISEVEN(COLUMNS(L:$K))) so if J2<>K2 then COLUMNS(L:$K) =2 so is even and the rule is applied.

Comment: =AND(I2<>J2,ISODD(COLUMNS(J:$K))) is another way.

Comment: Your formula =AND(J2<>K2),ISEVEN(COLUMNS($K:K))) would do nothing for the left hand cell but would change to =AND(K2<>L2),ISEVEN)COLUMNS($K:L))) and compare K2 with L2 which isn't what you want.

Comment: Tom - this one did the trick! Thanks so much (marked as answered)
=AND(I2<>J2,ISODD(COLUMNS(J:$K))) is another way. – Tom Sharpe Jul 15 at 10:51

Comment: Great! Glad we got there in the end.